# Sum sub-elements of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a multi-dimensional array like so:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [data] => Array(
      [value] => 10,
      [beta]  => 0.5
    ),
    [name]  => 'bob'
  ),
  [1] => Array(
    [data] => Array(
      [value] => 13,
      [beta]  => 0.6
    ),
    [name]  => 'Tim'
  ),
  [2] => Array(
    [data] => Array(
      [value] => 19,
      [beta]  => 0.3
    ),
    [name]  => 'Chris'
  )
)
```

Is there a way to sum the `value` element of each sub-sub-array without having to iterate the parent array? I am using CakePHP so was wondering if the `Hash` Utility might help with this.

Comment: No, and why would you look for one? Is there a way to count the ballots without having to iterate over each ballot? You can of course hide the iteration inside a function if it bothers you.

Comment: Well there is the [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function for 1-dimensional arrays, so it is feasible that a method exists for multidimensional arrays

Comment: `array_sum` has a loop inside, so it iterates. You can do the same for multidimensional arrays with `array_reduce`, but that also iterates and it will look much less familiar than a straight `foreach`.

Comment: For example: `$sum = array_reduce($arr, function($s, $i) { return $s += $i['data']['value']; });`

Comment: It may iterate but it's a native php function so is far more efficient at what it does, and doesn't require *me* to iterate. @Almo seems to have come up with a solution

Comment: I also give a solution in the comment above. But do take *any* solution and a straight manual `foreach` and benchmark them. You will be amazed at the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with:

```
$mResult = array_sum(array_map(function($rgItem)
{
   return $rgItem['data']['value'];
}, $rgData));
```